# SQL Contains Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've looked around on some Stack questions and answers but none of them seemed to work when being used, I'm using PDO as my connection to MySQL.

I tried using the statement bellow:

```
SELECT * FROM PROMOLOGS_initial WHERE CONTAINS(log_habboname, 'A')
```

And attempted to run that through row count, and it returned no rows back from the statement, I then tried putting the above query through a while loop and again, it returned no data from the Database, am I using this statement wrong? Is there another statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards instead

```
SELECT * FROM PROMOLOGS_initial WHERE log_habboname LIKE '%A%'
```

where `%` means any number of any character (possibly 0)
In this case the query will return all the tuples whose `log_habboname` attribute contain an **A**

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot for the future!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL only recognizes the `CONTAINS` SQL function when dealing with spatial data. It takes two graphics objects as arguments, and returns a 1 or 0 depending on if the first object completely contains the second. Designed as an implementation of the OpenGIS framework, the MySQL [CONTAINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html) function does not work on ordinary strings, and will produce an error if you try it. MySQL only recognizes the [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) and [STRCMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) functions when dealing with string of information.

Comment: I would have gone with your answer but the answer that helped me achieve what I wanted is what I'll go for, thanks anyway I appreciate the information! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM PROMOLOGS_initial WHERE log_habboname like '%A%'
```

assuming log_habboname is a column name.